# Calling Subs that already has a function in it

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

First of all , i've been googling around here n there , n i got stucked, i need a hand from someone. I already has a sub that contains function as parameter in it, Now the problem is how do i call this sub in my button , pls explain fully to me , i've been so desperate

```
Public Function AddDec(ByVal Valdec1 As Decimal, ByVal Valdec2 As Decimal) As Decimal
    AddDec = Valdec1 + Valdec2
End Function

Sub Finished(ByVal AddDec As Func(Of Decimal, Decimal, Decimal))
    If DetailCount1.Text.Length >= 10 Or DetailCount2.Text.Length >= 10 Then
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then TextBox1.Text = 0
        If DetailCount1.Text.Contains(",") Or DetailCount2.Text.Contains(",") Then
            Valdec2 = CDec(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = Adddec(Valdec1, Valdec2)
            MsgBox("HELP ME xD")
        Else
            ValDbl2 = CDbl(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = ValDbl1 + ValDbl2
        End If
    ElseIf Not DetailCount1.Text.Length >= 10 And Not DetailCount2.Text.Length >= 10 Then
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then TextBox1.Text = 0
        If kindbil1 = "Even" And Label2.Text = "Even" Then
            val2 = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = CInt(val1 + val2)
        ElseIf kindbil1 = "Deci" And Label2.Text = "Deci" Then
            Valdec2 = CDec(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Text = CDec(Valdec1 + Valdec2)
        ElseIf kindbil1 = "Deci" And Label2.Text = "Even" Then
            val2 = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
            Valdec2 = CDec(val2)
            TextBox1.Text = CDec(Valdec1 + Valdec2)
        ElseIf kindbil1 = "Even" And Label2.Text = "Deci" Then
            Valdec2 = CDec(TextBox1.Text)
            Valdec1 = CDec(val1)
            TextBox1.Text = CDec(Valdec1 + Valdec2)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little hard to understand what you want to do, but I guess you want to call `Finished` with the `AddDec` method as argument for the `AddDec` parameter.

To do so, you have to use [the `AddressOf` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
Finished(AddressOf AddDec)
```

Comment: thx alot man. Now, i realize i lack reference and basic about using parameter. Thank god you were there xD